# If possible we can know the historic price for EOS ram from block?

Tags: cleos, nodeos, ram

is there exist a table so that we can know historic price from EOS mainnet?
Or if we want to know the price of EOS Ram on specific time, which data we can get from EOS mainnet?

I know https://eos.feexplorer.io/ can help people know the history, but my question is how they can do that?

Answer (score 1):

### Update:

You could use [demux](https://github.com/EOSIO/demux-js) to replay the blockchain then listen to RAM trades to create a mongodb database of each change in the RAM market table.

---

The only way I've seen is to query the table:

```
cleos -u https://nodes.get-scatter.com:443 get table eosio eosio rammarket

    {
      "rows": [{
          "supply": "10000000000.0000 RAMCORE",
          "base": {
            "balance": "11870290976 RAM",
            "weight": "0.50000000000000000"
          },
          "quote": {
            "balance": "5789275.3804 EOS",
            "weight": "0.50000000000000000"
          }
        }
      ],
      "more": false
    }
```

---

### Price Formula:

[image]

---

[image]

---

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-get-table

https://www.eosrp.io/ is open source as well if you care to look through their code: https://github.com/eosnewyork/erp

Comment: thanks for you answer, but this is the lastest price, not historic price.